# Unable to Download Application, Application could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios, enterprise, provisioning-profile, ota

I have problem doing OTA installation for my iPad  application. I updated my enterprise certificate last week. and i created new dev/dist certificate and provisioning profile. Xcode organizer shows the correct expire date. when i try to install the app from the link , it downloads half and shows me the error "Unable to donwload Application, could not be installed at this time." I've done OTA installation like more than 50 times before. I rechecked everything. It's not problem of invalid link, or selecting wrong provisioning profile. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I checked the device log and it says:

```
May  1 13:15:32 unknown installd[2455] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May  1 13:15:32 unknown installd[2455] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May  1 13:15:32 unknown installd[2455] <Error>: 00381000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620394
May  1 13:15:32 unknown installd[2455] <Error>: 00381000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.8zrx0B/foo_extracted/Payload/Hra.app
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem here as well. Have you managed to get it to work?

Comment: yea. The solution is to create the distribution certificate from the team agent when u renew the certificate.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create the distribution certificate from the team agent when u renew the certificate. –

Comment: Please accept the answer as well. It is fine to accept your own answer. There is a check mark under the answer's score.

Answer (score 6):

This answer helped me, thank you very much.

Here are my exact steps. I was building an ad hoc from an Xcode project created for me, so the bundle identifier was already created and I had to match it in the steps below.

In your Apple Developer portal:

- need to create new certificates first: Distribution Certificate, then toggle to make sure it's reflected in the Developer Certificate. I downloaded both certificates to my computer just out of habit, but Xcode 4.3.2 doesn't require that Keychain Access request step anymore.
- Create App ID (make sure it matches the com. bundle created in XCode if that's already been created. In this case the Info file listed the bundle identifier as a wildcard: com.mydomain.${PRODUCT_NAME}. The name of my product has upper and lower case. The App ID is case sensitive so it should match this Xcode bundle identifier/product name exactly.
- add any new devices.
- Create Development and Distribution Provisioning files - download, and drag each into Xcode.

In XCode:

- in Build info file, it worked for me that Code Signing Entity fields were all set to Don't Code Sign
- to create archive, clean Target, then making sure the scheme points to a connected device, go to Product -> Archive
- the Organizer view of Archives should come up - select the one just built, select Distribute then select Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc and in the Choose an Identity to Sign With choose Refresh in the drop down, then just leave it on the default and click Next.
- Choose Save For Enterprise Distribution - you only need to fill out the top two fields; the url on the server to the .ipa file, and the name of the app.
- then upload the files to the directory specified in the last step, customize and send out the link i.e. itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://yourdomain.com/yourdirectories/yourAppName.plist

Comment: An update to this - it also never hurts to be sure you are running the latest version of XCode. If the devices trying to run your OTA link have a newer version of iOS than what's supported by your SDK there can also be problems.